# How to adjust UITextView Scrolling During Deletion?

Tags: iphone, ios5, uitextview

I have used `UITextView` which only show two lines of text.During editing if user enter 3 to 4 lines and then perform deletion cursor is not visible.Please suggest how to adjust cursor position of `UITextview` during deletion so that text in textview is visible?

Comment: When you want the cursor to be visible and where? As far as I know the UITextView will not automatically scroll as the user types in more lines. Probably the  solution is making the UITextView bigger so as to show 4 lines.

Comment: I have to display textView of Fixed size.which can display text of 2 lines at time.I have problem when user types 4 to 5 lines then delete one or two lines after that cursor is not visible.

Comment: is it necessary to use UITextView? if possible u can use UITextField , use custom and then you can give it any size . !!

Comment: Yes it is necessary to use UITextView , Because if user types number of lines at that time scrolling also needed to show topmost lines